# I want to get woocommerce reviews by product id and display it in a template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, review

I want to fetch woocommerce product reviews by product id or anything else and want to display it in a template created by me.

Comment: i have got idea and completed it using $wp_query and loading single-product-reviews.php in that template

Answer (score 22):

Woocommerce made a reviews out of regular wordpress comments.

The simple way is to get a comments of 'post_type' => 'product', that will get raw comment data. In order to display proper woocommerce review out of that you need to apply a callback function witch is 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments'.

The whole thing is:

```
<?php
    $args = array ('post_type' => 'product');
    $comments = get_comments( $args );
    wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ), $comments);
?>
```

If you want to get the comment by product ID then you need to change that $args:

```
$args = array ('post_id' => 123);
```

To customize it more check out that references:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments
http://codex.wordpress.org/get_comments

The 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' function uses a template located in plugins/woocomerce/templates/single-product/review.php

Comment: Simple and works great. How can I display the review form as well?

Answer (score 7):

To display comments (reviews) simply use:

`echo comments_template();`

on the product page.

For more details visit [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template)

Answer (score 4):

```
<div id="reviews">
<div id="comments">
    <h2><?php
        if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'yes' && ( $count = $product->get_rating_count() ) )
            printf( _n( '%s review for %s', '%s reviews for %s', $count, 'woocommerce' ), $count, get_the_title() );
        else
            _e( 'Reviews', 'woocommerce' );
    ?></h2>

    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>

        <ol class="commentlist">
            <?php wp_list_comments( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ) ) ); ?>
        </ol>

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) :
            echo '<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">';
            paginate_comments_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_comment_pagination_args', array(
                'prev_text' => '&larr;',
                'next_text' => '&rarr;',
                'type'      => 'list',
            ) ) );
            echo '</nav>';
        endif; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-noreviews"><?php _e( 'There are no reviews yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_review_rating_verification_required' ) === 'no' || wc_customer_bought_product( '', get_current_user_id(), $product->id ) ) : ?>

    <div id="review_form_wrapper">
        <div id="review_form">
            <?php
                $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();

                $comment_form = array(
                    'title_reply'          => have_comments() ? __( 'Add a review', 'woocommerce' ) : __( 'Be the first to review', 'woocommerce' ) . ' &ldquo;' . get_the_title() . '&rdquo;',
                    'title_reply_to'       => __( 'Leave a Reply to %s', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'comment_notes_before' => '',
                    'comment_notes_after'  => '',
                    'fields'               => array(
                        'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span></label> ' .
                                    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30" aria-required="true" /></p>',
                        'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span></label> ' .
                                    '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" aria-required="true" /></p>',
                    ),
                    'label_submit'  => __( 'Submit', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'logged_in_as'  => '',
                    'comment_field' => ''
                );

                if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'yes' ) {
                    $comment_form['comment_field'] = '<p class="comment-form-rating"><label for="rating">' . __( 'Your Rating', 'woocommerce' ) .'</label><select name="rating" id="rating">
                        <option value="">' . __( 'Rate&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                        <option value="5">' . __( 'Perfect', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                        <option value="4">' . __( 'Good', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                        <option value="3">' . __( 'Average', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                        <option value="2">' . __( 'Not that bad', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                        <option value="1">' . __( 'Very Poor', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                    </select></p>';
                }

                $comment_form['comment_field'] .= '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . __( 'Your Review', 'woocommerce' ) . '</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>';

                comment_form( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_comment_form_args', $comment_form ) );
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php else : ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-verification-required"><?php _e( 'Only logged in customers who have purchased this product may leave a review.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes Sir, I've tried my level best to displays the reviews at the bottom of its default tabs, but I can't do it for many days and finally I find your method to display the particular Product's reviews. It working great. Awesome Sir Awesome.

But one thing more to display the product's reviews dynamically on single-product.php
// Get the Id of product dynamically and print them (reviews) by ids.

```
global $product;
$id = $product->id;

echo $id.",";
$args = array ('post_type' => 'product', 'post_id' => $id);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ), $comments);
```

Just Paste this code in your single-product.php file see the result. It will show as you want.

Answer (score 2):

I have been recently having the same struggle and I came up with this solution that allows you to output reviews from all products on a single page.

```
//Display all product reviews
if (!function_exists('display_all_reviews')) {
function display_all_reviews(){
    $args = array(
       'status' => 'approve',
       'type' => 'review'
    );

    // The Query
    $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
    $comments = $comments_query->query( $args );

    // Comment Loop
    if ( $comments ) {
        echo "<ol>";
        foreach ( $comments as $comment ): ?>
        <?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) : ?>
            <p class="meta waiting-approval-info">
                <em><?php _e( 'Thanks, your review is awaiting approval', 'woocommerce' ); ?></em>
            </p>
            <?php endif;  ?>
            <li itemprop="reviews" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-review-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>">
                <div id="review-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" class="review_container">
                    <div class="review-avatar">
                        <?php echo get_avatar( $comment->comment_author_email, $size = '50' ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="review-author">
                        <div class="review-author-name" itemprop="author"><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?></div>
                        <div class='star-rating-container'>
                            <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" class="star-rating" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true ) ); ?>">
                                <span style="width:<?php echo get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true )*22; ?>px"><span itemprop="ratingValue"><?php echo get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true ); ?></span> <?php _e('out of 5', 'woocommerce'); ?></span>

                                    <?php
                                        $timestamp = strtotime( $comment->comment_date ); //Changing comment time to timestamp
                                        $date = date('F d, Y', $timestamp);
                                    ?>
                            </div>
                            <em class="review-date">
                                <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="<?php echo $comment->comment_date; ?>"><?php echo $date; ?></time>
                            </em>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="review-text">
                        <div itemprop="description" class="description">
                            <?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>           
            </div>
        </li>

        <?php 
        endforeach;
        echo "</ol>";
    } else {
        echo "This product hasn't been rated yet.";
    }
}
}
```

Add the above function to your functions.php file.
After this you can use this function on your theme wherever you would like by calling it like this:

```
<?php echo display_all_reviews(); ?>
```

I also created a tutorial here https://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/get-woocommerce-customer-reviews-from-all-products-display-average-and-all-ratings-in-a-histogram-without-a-plugin/ that also includes functions to output average product rating, total count of all ratings from all products and all product review histogram.

Answer (score 1):

In `woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs.php`

If you run a `print_r()` on `$tabs` after it has been declared you'll see that a portion of the output is the following:

```
[reviews] => Array (
    [title] => Reviews (3)
    [priority] => 30
    [callback] => comments_template
)
```

This means that the callback is the function: `comments_template()`.

Since this function doesn't accept a `$post_id` parameter, the would need to be called within *the loop*.

However, the function does accept a parameter of the template file to use, so to answer the OP's direct question of how to use a custom template file - you can use the function like so:

```
comments_template( string $file = '/comments.php', bool $separate_comments = false );
```

[This ^ was taken directly from the codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_template/)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late for you Kishan since you posted a a while ago, but perhaps it will help someone else.

We just developed a free plugin to display woocommerce reviews by product id with shortcode. It also inserts Schema of the product.

Check it out, it's free: https://shopitpress.com/plugins/sip-reviews-shortcode-woocommerce/

Comment: add relevant text here. External link only answers are not encourage as link mya change in future

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot to get any built-in function for this but i didn't. Then i wrote my own query. It might help you:

```
$comment_and_reviews = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wpc.comment_author,wpc.comment_author_email,wpc.comment_date,wpc.comment_content,wpcm.meta_value AS rating FROM `" . $wpdb->prefix . "comments` AS wpc INNER JOIN  `" . $wpdb->prefix . "commentmeta` AS wpcm ON wpcm.comment_id = wpc.comment_id AND wpcm.meta_key = 'rating' WHERE wpc.comment_post_id = '" . $p_id . "' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I take a week to find and had found a easy way to do it.

If you want **bring review product to a page** just using WP_Query and put
`echo comments_template()` inside

or if you want a custom template review you can using template from wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product-reviews.php and put inside WP_Query

Example in my case, I want bring review from product id 33051 to home page

```
<?php   
    $args = array('post_type' => 'product','id' => 33051);
    $result = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $result-> have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $result->have_posts() ) : $result->the_post(); ?>
    <?php comments_template(); // you can custom template by code in single-product-reviews.php
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```