# woocommerce - call review form in other than product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to provide the woocommerce product review form in a page other than product page using product id, is there any way to call the review form like this?

Answer (score 2):

Just try this in template

```
comments_template( ‘woocommerce/single-product-reviews’ );
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is a plugin you can use: https://wordpress.org/plugins/twb-woocommerce-reviews/
also one more solution here: [I want to get woocommerce reviews by product id and display it in a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372368/i-want-to-get-woocommerce-reviews-by-product-id-and-display-it-in-a-template)