# Woo-commerce reviews and review form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Hello we have custom product page as single-product.php and want to add reviews and its form but we are not getting its function or anything so how can we add reviews in custom single-product page?can anyone suggest me?

Comment: How do you used single-product.php have you copied it from woocommerce plugin and follow the way how woocommerce template override functionality works?

Comment: no i made it custom i didn't copy from woo-commerce

Comment: You can just use `<?php wc_get_template_part( 'single', 'prodcut-reviews' ); ?>`

Comment: but it doesn't give review form and reviews

Comment: Actually if you override template in woocommerce method then all the default theme will work better you may check and get help from this link more about template overriding - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: its not about template overriding i have single-product.php whose design and structure are vase different then default product single page that's why i made single-product.php and now i have copy the file inside the theme also with woo-commerce folder and i have paste the all php file of templates inside that folder and placed the above code also but it's not giving that's the issue

Answer (score -1):

use this on single-product.php

```
<?php wc_get_template_part('single', 'product-reviews'); ?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Doesn't work without calling `comments_template()` before loading this template. Please, observe the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106667/woocommerce-call-review-form-in-other-than-product-page